# c# program does not get my ip address if executed by jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins

My c# program does not get my ip address if executed by jenkins while it does being executed without.

Jenkins and c# program run on a windows machine (no slave).
Jenkins runs on the same machine and is started as a service by local system account. The c# program runs as a windows batch build step of a free-style build project (not pipe).

```cs
IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in addresses)
{
    Console.Writeline($"ip = {ip}");
}
```

- which prints my IPv6 and then my IPv4 address without jenkins.
- which prints ::1 and 127.0.0.1 with jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins is on your machine also? What user security context does Jenkins execute your program as? If your program is not run as a particular user and adopts the credentials Jenkins uses because Jenkins spawned it, then it might not have enough permissions to query all the io addresses on the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put printing the ip address into a stage of a pipeline:

```
echo InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress
```

... and used in-process script approval to allow

- staticMethod java.net.InetAddress getLocalHost
- method java.net.InetAddress getHostAddress

Now my c# program is also allowed to query the ip address.

@CaiusJard: You were right pointing out the permissions. Thank you. :-)